# How to use jQuery file uploader plugin in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, jquery-file-upload

I want to upload image files to the server, but with Polymer 1.0 iron-ajax, it is not possible. So, I am trying out the blueimp's [jquery-file-upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), but I couldn't figure it out in the code.

Code :

```
<template>
  <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="api/upload_image/">
</template>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log( "Triggered" );
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});

Polymer({
    is: 'x-custom'
});

</script>
```

It will be great if I can make an iron-ajax POST call to the URL, and I can display some message on response. Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Whenever I upload a file, there is no data received on the server side, and the log statement is not working.

Comment: Ok, doesn't look Polymer related and I don't know jQuery.

Comment: Is there any polymer 1.0 element to achieve the same, i.e, to upload a file to the server, that would be awesome. :-)

Comment: @RAGHURAMAN other than the lack of information for helping your issue, there are some element catalogues like [customelements.io](https://customelements.io/) where you can find elements, also those that you want, for example [this one](https://customelements.io/winhowes/file-upload/) ([docs & demo](https://winhowes.github.io/file-upload/components/file-upload/))